# Why should I use View argument instead of whatever I want?

Tags: android

Here is my simple example. I defined a button in main.xml file, and 'on Click' property to call my onClickk method when button01 is tapped. It is perfectly fine, but I don't understand why should I pass `View` object when I want to pass simply `Button` and do no casting.

If I'm passing the button as Button the application stops unexpectedly when I tap the button.

```
public class Als extends Activity {

    Button button01; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button01.setText("something");

    }

    public void onClickk(View button01) {
        Button but = (Button) button01;
        but.setText("Cooool");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the OnClick event is part of the View object.  Button simply inherits/uses it.  When the OnClick is called by the framework, it's the View object calling it, not the button, so it passes a View, which you then need to know what to typecast it to.

Comment: On top of this, you can simplify that code in your method by just using `(Button)button01.setText("Cooool");`.

Answer (score 2):

Also, instead of using an intentional typo to create your own method, you could instead do something like this:

```
public class Als extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button01;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button01 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button01.setText("something");
        button01.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button01:
            button01.setText("Cooool");
            break;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```